# Using a redirect link in rel=canonical link tag bad for SEO?

Tags: seo, redirects, 301-redirect, rel-canonical

I have in my Django site's template:

```
<link rel="canonical" href="https://www.my-domain.example/post/1"/>
```

But the actual link is `https://www.my-actual-domain.example/post/1`

`my-domain.example` gets redirected (301) to `my-actual-domain.example`

Is it better (from a SEO POV) to have the canonical_tag as `my-actual-domain.example` than having `my-domain.example` even though the latter redirects?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The canonical should point to the URL with a status code 200.

Pointing the canonical to a redirect beats the purpose and makes it more likely that Google ignores it.